# Getting the error "No library found for this namespace"

Tags: jsf, primefaces, netbeans6.8

I am using Netbeans6.8 and trying to build a simple project with JSF2 and Primefaces.

Placed the jars jsf-impl-2.0.3.jar,jstl-1.0.2.jar, jsf-api-2.0.3.jar, primefaces-2.2.1.jar in the lib folder and I get this error in my NetBeans editor "No library found for this namespace"

My code for the login.xhtml page is as below.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"> 
<h:head> 
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="themes/bluesky/skin.css" /> 
</h:head> 
<h:body> 
   .....
```

Can anyone help me like what might be the reason I am getting this error.

I had my faces-config.xml placed properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your default `xmlns` namespace is wrong. It should point to `www.w3.org`, not `www.w3c.org`.

Fix it accordingly:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
     ...
>
```

Comment: Thanks. It helped!! Not sure but after restarting my IDE, it is working even with 'W3C'.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Will do this from now.